# Binding this to nested functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**How can I bind `this` to the React component when dealing with a nested function?**

Here is a skeleton example. The reason that `function2` is nested is so that you can get access to the variables defined in `function1`

```
class View extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            a = null;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        function1();
    }

    function1(){
        console.log(this); //will show the component correctly

        var param1 = 10;

        //call a second function that's defined inside the first function
        function2();

        function function2(){
            console.log(this); //undefined

            var a = param1*2;

            this.setState({ a : a}); //won't work because this is undefined
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p> Hello </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the nested `function2`? It's only accessible within `function1` and you're not calling it.

Comment: use arrow function for function2 is one option, `const function2 = () => {...}` - though, you never use function2, so there's no issue

Comment: I edited my post to call function2() from within function1().

The goal is to also have function3() and function4() that can all use the same initial variables defined in function1()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just use arrow functions? That would make sure `this` is referenced properly. I am assuming you can use `ES6`.

```
function1 = () => {
    console.log(this);

    var param1 = 10;

    const function2 = () => {
      console.log(this);

      var a = param1*2;

      this.setState({ a }); 
    }

    function2(); // inkove the function
}
```

OR if you only want to use `ES5`, then this could also work

```
function1() {
    console.log(this);

    var param1 = 10;

    function function2() {
      console.log(this);

      var a = param1*2;

      this.setState({ a }); 
    }

    function2.bind(this)() // to invoke the function
}
```

Comment: How do you then call function2 if it's a const? Simply using `function2()` doesn't work.

Comment: You can call it using `function2()` in `ES6`.

Comment: that didn't work for me. Please note I updated my code and added in where I'm trying to call `function2()`... maybe that matters.

Comment: But in your snippet, you are invoking the function even before declaring it? That will not work. Try invoking it after the function declaration.

Comment: I thought due to hoisting it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Can we modify the value of param1 ? @NanduKalidindi

Answer (score 3):

You could keep a reference to `this` and use that variable inside `function2`.

```
function1(){
    var self = this;
    .....
    function function2(){
        console.log(self);
        ....
    } 
}
```

You can also set the context of that function using `apply`, `bind` or `call`. For example:

```
function2.call(this);
```

Comment: Thank you. I found this useful for when I use `btn.addEventListener` then call `function2()` which then tries to call `this.setState` which I have now replaced with `self.setState`