# Can I use the arrow function within a class method?

Tags: nested, closures, arrow-functions, class-method

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676650/binding-this-to-nested-functions-in-react), I saw closure was implemented, but I want to keep this class method while still being able to access the class properties. My goal is to pass this innerFunc to the setTimeOut(), but previously, using the commented out function below the arrow function, "this" could not be recognized. Right now, with this arrow function, I am receiving the following error per screenshot.  Thanks in advance!

```
class TV {
constructor (id = "tv-0", name = "Blank Slate") {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    console.log("NEW TV CREATED: ", this);
    console.log("ID: ", this.id);
    this.gifArr = gifCarousel_dict[this.name];
    console.log("Media selection for this tv: ", this.gifArr);
    this.index = getSecondPart(id);
    this.channel = 0;
    this.displayed = $(".displayed")[this.index];
    this.cnv = $(".static")[this.index];
    console.log(this.cnv);
    this.canvas = {
        c: this.cnv.getContext("2d"),
        cw: this.cnv.offsetWidth,
        ch: this.cnv.offsetHeight
    }
    
    this.staticScrn = this.canvas.c.createImageData(this.canvas.cw, this.canvas.ch);

    console.log("This canvas element: ", this.cnv);
    //Static display 
    this.isStatic = true;
    // this.staticTo;
    this.runStatic = this.runStatic.bind(this);

    this.chnButton = $(".channel")[this.index];
    console.log("Channel Button for new TV here: ", this.chnButton);
    this.changeChannel = this.changeChannel.bind(this);

    this.setupChannels = function() {
        this.chnButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.changeChannel());
    }

    this.setupChannels();
    
}


changeChannel () {


            ++this.channel;
            if (this.channel > this.gifArr.length)
                this.channel = 1;

            // this.classList.remove("pristine");
            this.chnButton.classList.remove("pristine");

            // this.style.transform = `rotate(${channel * 360/(gifData.length + 1)}deg)`;
            this.chnButton.style.transform = `rotate(${this.channel * 360/(this.gifArr.length + 1)}deg)`;

            // theCanvas = document.querySelectorAll(".static")[idx]

            // cnv.classList.remove("hide");
            this.cnv.classList.remove("hide");
            this.displayed.classList.add("hide"); //CAUSING PROBLEMS

            if (!this.isStatic)
                this.runStatic();


            const innerFunc = () => {
                this.cnv.classList.add("hide");
                this.displayed.classList.remove("hide");

                this.displayed.src = this.gifArr[this.channel - 1].src;
                this.displayed.alt = this.gifArr[this.channel - 1].alt;

                this.isStatic = false;

                clearTimeout(this.staticTO);
            }   

            setTimeout(innerFunc(), 300);


            // setTimeout(function () {
            //  // console.log("Lexical scope: ", this);
            //  // cnv.classList.add("hide");
            //  this.cnv.classList.add("hide");
            //  this.displayed.classList.remove("hide");

            //  this.displayed.src = this.gifArr[this.channel - 1].src;
            //  this.displayed.alt = this.gifArr[this.channel - 1].alt;

            //  this.isStatic = false;

            //  clearTimeout(this.staticTO);
            // }, 300);
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error was not in my method of invoking the function but just where I was trying to access what I thought was the src file of the gifArr. It still contained two key values even though I was trying to select only one. First, I mapped only the "file" key-value pairs to a new array:

> this.gifArr_src = this.gifArr.map(({desc, ...rest}) => rest);

Then I accessed them inside setTimeout()'s arrow function using the line:

> this.displayed.src = this.gifArr_src[this.channel - 1]['file'];

**NOTE: Fairly certain this is not the most efficient or follows good practice, but it works for now.